# Export Data to Excel, Date format changed as text

Tags: python, django, excel, export-to-excel

When I export my data from my Website [python-django] to 'Excel' all the fields come correctly and the date field also displays good, but the problem is it appears as Text and hence I cant apply the auto filters and other advanced options which work well with a 'date' format. So I want the date to be exported as 'date' type only. Are there any settings or anything else that we could do to get this in place.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please, show us some code

Comment: How are you exporting the data? This is probably a database issue rather than a django one?

Answer (score 0):

After you've imported the data change the format of the column in excel..

- Right click the top of the column, select 'format cells'
- Click the 'Number' tab, then select 'Date' and choose the format that matches you're output
- When selecting a date format you may need to change the Locale to match your database setup.

You should now be able to filter on date.

(this is for MS Office 2010)

Comment: @juankysmith I took a format which is a standard form of date in excel and made all my date data in that format. And when any column data in the exported excel matches the same format I parsed it to show as date type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Changing from the Excel is quite an easy thing to do. I think i made it very clear in the question that i wanted a solution from the coding perspective.  To quote from the question: I want the date to be exported as 'date' type only.

Comment: I woud love to know why this question is down rated so that next time i try implementing that and ask questions in a better way. It would have been even better if whoever has downrated it would have given a reason prior to me asking :)

Comment: It's great that you want to improve your questions on here. I'd suggest you start by reading the faq - http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Then maybe have a look at Matt Gemmels blog post - http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/. I assume the two people who down voted your question are the same two who upvoted jaunkysmiths comment.